# How to distinguish between validation and system errors in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When a save is peformed, the callback is passed an `error` parameter. What's the correct way to distinguish between system/internal errors and validation errors inside the callback?

```
    model.save(function (err, model) {
        if (validation err) {
            // do smth
        } else {
            // do smth else
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) regarding validation:

> Errors returned after failed validation contain an errors object
>   holding the actual ValidatorErrors. Each ValidatorError has a type,
>   path, and value property providing us with a little more error
>   handling flexibility.

```
console.log(err.errors.color.value) // prints "grease"
console.log(err.name) // prints "ValidationError"
console.log(err.message) // prints "Validation failed"
```

And:

> After a validation error, the document will also have the same errors
>   property available:

```
toy.errors.color.message === err.errors.color.message
```